# Pandas time series-specific operations in Altair

Tags: python, altair

Is it possible to perform groupby operations for datetime object in Altair using transform_aggregate function? I am trying to replicate some of the time series plot from "Example: Visualizing Seattle Bicycle Counts" example of Jake VDP's book - https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.11-working-with-time-series.html

Does transform_aggregate allow time-series specific operations like resample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Altair has built-in time groupings using the [TimeUnit transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/timeunit.html), which can be used either via an explicit transform, or via encoding shorthands.

Here is an example of reproducing one of the charts from that section of the book – note that the Vega-Lite renderer becomes slow when data grows to tens of thousands of entries, so I use [altair_data_server](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_data_server/) to serve the data and limit the chart to the first year:

```
# Load the data
# !curl -o FremontBridge.csv https://data.seattle.gov/api/views/65db-xm6k/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('FremontBridge.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
data.columns = ['Date', 'Total', 'East', 'West']
df = data.iloc[:24 * 365]  # limit to first year of data

# Draw the chart
import altair as alt
alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')  # handle larger datasets

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().transform_fold(
    ['Total', 'East', 'West'],
).encode(
    x='hours(Date):T',
    y='sum(value):Q',
    color='key:N'
)
```

[image]

This timeUnit grammar is quite flexible, and allows you to split and group by multiple date attributes in a single chart; for example, here's the trend faceted by day of the week:

```
alt.Chart(df).transform_fold(
    ['Total', 'East', 'West']
).mark_line().encode(
    x='hours(Date):T',
    y='sum(value):Q',
    color='key:N',
    facet=alt.Facet('day(Date):O', columns=4)
).properties(width=200, height=150)
```

[image]